# gcc cannot find stddef.h after gcc upgrade

Tags: c, gcc

I am using RHEL7 and wanted an updated gcc compiler.  Following instructions posted [here](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-gcc-on-centos-6) I installed gcc 7.3.0 under ~/bin/sourceInstallation

Checking my versions:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.3.0

$ sudo gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
```

Great so far.  However, when attempting to install PyHDF I got an error stating cc1 could not be found.

```
$ python setup.py install
angry text angry text angry text 
cannot find cc1
```

Apparently the GCC_EXEC_PREFIX was not properly set (no idea what that means), but I got around it by updating my path in .bashrc

```
# add non-standard gcc compiler path
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin/sourceInstallations/gcc_7_3_0_release_build/gcc/
export GCC_EXEC_PREFIX=~/bin/sourceInstallations/gcc_7_3_0_release_build/gcc/
```

Is that fix correct?

NOW when compiling a simple program I get an error about stdio.h not finding stddef.h

```
$ gcc -o dummy dummy.c
In file included from dummy.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:33:11: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
# include <stddef.h>
       ^~~~~~~~~~
$ compilation terminated.
```

I know stddef.h exists within the path since it is found under a directory explicitly added to the path and GCC_EXEC_PREFIX

```
$ locate stddef.h
~/bin/sourceInstallations/gcc_7_3_0_release_build/gcc/include/stddef.h
```

Is gcc calling stdio.h from the wrong spot.  From the error message: /usr/include/stdio.h:33:11...shouldn't it be calling stdio.h from my ~/bin/sourceInstallations directory?

At this point I have no ideas about how to fix this, and I don't really understand exactly what the problem is.  Is this separate gcc installation just hosed?  Should I NOT expect it to work?

All this being said, the original gcc still works.  If I compile my program like so

```
$ sudo gcc -o dummy dummy.c
```

It compiles fine.  I needed a newer version of gcc to compile somebody else's software...maybe I should just do without. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you really followed those instructions, your new gcc is at `/usr/local/bin/gcc`, not `~/bin/sourceInstallation`. Are you trying to run the uninstalled gcc from the build directory?

Comment: You are correct.  $ which gcc tells me /usr/local/bin/gcc

Comment: So what happens if you undo your modifications to `PATH` and `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX` and use `gcc`?

Comment: This gets me back to the cc1 error: gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Well, I actually had the same problem a few days ago. I use VS Code and when I tried to compile my code using GCC, a green line appeared under my includes. What I've done is I uninstalled GCC and then reinstalled only c and c++ packages from the installation manager and it worked.